# Use thread local store lua_State

Tags: lua, thread-local, iocp

I need to use Lua in IOCP, and use Thread local Storage to store `lua_State *`. I should use `lua_close()` destroy the lua_State before the thread destroyed, but the work thread is created by IOCP.

The question is when is the right time to call `lua_close`?

```
static DWORD WINAPI work_thread_proc(void* parameter){
    lua_State * L = TlsGetValue(tls_lua_key);
    if(NULL = L){
          L=luaL_newstate();
          //DO some initialze for L...

          TlsSetValue(tls_lua_key,L);
    }

}


//..... other place call
QueueUserWorkItem(&work_thread_proc, req, WT_EXECUTELONGFUNCTION);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use it like this.

```
__declspec(thread) lua_State *tls_LuaState = NULL;
// close lua state on exit thread.
void NTAPI TLS_CloseLuaState(PVOID module, DWORD reason, PVOID reserved)
{
    if(NULL != ){
        lua_close(tls_LuaState);
    }
}

#pragma section(".CRT$XLB",long,read)
    __declspec(allocate(".CRT$XLB"))
        PIMAGE_TLS_CALLBACK p_thread_callback_base = TLS_CloseLuaState;
```

Comment: if(NULL != ){ is wronge , you need change to  if(NULL != tls_LuaState)